# After running the code it shows this message

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was getting the following error page after running a spring boot application and trying to access it in the browser.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Feb 10 04:41:11 IST 2024 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404).

This is my `pom.xml` configuration file

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Following is the main Java file

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.course.courseapplication.controller" })

public class CourseapplicationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseapplicationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first have a controller class annotated with @Restcontroller.then have a method with @Requestmapping annotation.this will provide an endpoint to the browser and you will be able to print out.
have sth like this:
@RestController

public class mycontroller {

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")

public String helloWorld() {
    return "hello world,welcome to spring boot";
}
```

}

then in your local host provide the endpoint /hello